# Unable to change a single pixel with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I've tried so many ways of changing a pixel in Pygame, and none of them works with me...

```
import pygame
import random

width = 640
height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:
    x = random.randint(0, width-1)
    y = random.randint(0, height-1)
    red = random.randint(0, 255)
    green = random.randint(0, 255)
    blue = random.randint(0, 255)
    screen.set_at((x, y), (red, green, blue))
    clock.tick(10)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(240)
```

Nothing happens, just the black screen until I close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're following [this tutorial](https://lorenzod8n.wordpress.com/2007/12/16/pygame-tutorial-5-pixels/) but you've indented a few essential lines in the wrong place. Remember, Python is *white space sensitive*; indentation matters!

The last two lines should not be inside the `for` loop block, they should be in the `while` loop block.

```
while running:
    # code that draws pixel

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(240)
```

These lines update the display and compute the time between frames.

The way you had it, inside the if statement, the pixel would never get drawn until the `pygame.QUIT` event was triggered.